# Create chatbot type application for wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frontend, chatbot

I have a plugin where I want to implement chat feature, and I want to display a chat icon in all over wordpress i.e (frontend and backend) and when clicking on that icon, it will display the options for chat. I am not sure how do I make a chat icon appear everywhere in wordpress.

Does anyone have any experience or idea?

Comment: You should specify your question. For starters, **which plugin do you use**?

Comment: I have my own plugin I created, I want to show a chat icon on every wordpress page in bottom right corner, and handle everything using methods in my plugin, I am not sure how do i get the chat icon display in every page. i hope i was able to clear you.

Comment: You can put your chat icon in your footer.php before </body> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fe_chat_app');
```

this solved my problem. it added the php file in the head of my wordpress theme file from which i was able to load the JS file in WordPress.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.